# Prevent suspend if logged in via ssh to another machine

Tags: ssh, suspend

Previously I have found that Ubuntu would not suspend if an SSH session was open, but on a new laptop install of Ubuntu 11.04 I find that the laptop will go into suspend according to it's normal schedule, even though there was an open SSH connection. Suspending means the connection is closed, and tasks taking place on the remote machine are cancelled.

Any idea how to get the previous behaviour back?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/51179

Comment: Have a look at the selected answer here: [Prevent machine from sleeping when ssh connections are on](https://askubuntu.com/questions/521620/prevent-machine-from-sleeping-when-ssh-connections-are-on)

Answer (score 3):

You could use [caffeine](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/app/caffeine/) and add the SSH application to the list of applications.