# How to disable shutdown or reboot in 14.04 when users are connected via SSH?

Tags: 14.04, ssh, shutdown

I've a group of Ubuntu Trusty desktop PCs in my office, and usually I ssh to them and install updates remotely from the command line. Unfortunately, sometimes local users decide to shutdown those PCs, breaking the update process.

I'd like to prevent those users to shutdown, reboot or suspend their PCs when there's an SSH session active. How can I do it?

I've tried `molly-guard`, but doesn't prevent GUI users from shutting down the system (it doesn't seem to affect GUI users).
I've seen also this question, but didn't understand if it's applicable also to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS or not (and I'm not sure how to apply it):
 [disable shutdown/suspend if there is other user logged in via ssh](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51179/disable-shutdown-suspend-if-there-is-other-user-logged-in-via-ssh)

Answer (score 7):

This could be done using a PolKit policy, if you have admin privileges.

Create a `.pkla` file in `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d` (say `disable-shutdown.pkla`), containing:

```
[Disable Shutdown, etc.]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.reboot-multiple-sessions;org.freedesktop.login1.power-off-multiple-sessions;org.freedesktop.login1.suspend-multiple-sessions;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions
ResultAny=no
ResultInactive=no
ResultActive=no
```

The `-multiple-sessions` part is for when multiple users are logged in - there are similar actions without that suffix. This disables these actions from the GUI, as far as I can tell.

Note that this method only blocks reboot, etc., commands issued from GUI. To block reboot, etc., commands from command line, one may use molly-guard - as explained in [Disabling shutdown command for all users, even root - consequences?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17187/disabling-shutdown-command-for-all-users-even-root-consequences/17255#17255)

Comment: Easy and effective, this solves my problem, many thanks! One remark: with this configuration, I've seen that regular, non-administrative users can't shutdown or reboot the system when I'm connected via SSH, but nothing prevents my privileged user to shutdown/reboot/etc the system (and there are no warnings about other users connected). This isn't a problem for me, since I'm the only administrator of those PCs.

Comment: @gerlos Via the GUI or via `sudo shutdown`?

Comment: Via the shutdown item in top left menu in the GUI (didn't try via cli).

Comment: @gerlos Instead of `no`, if you use `auth_admin`, do you get a password prompt?

Comment: No, using `auth_admin` nothing warns my privileged user about other users connected neither asks for a password. Only regular users get a warning and a prompt for an administrative password to continue.

Comment: Also there's no warning when I run `sudo reboot`, even with `molly-guard` installed (not sure if this is intended or not, molly-guard works fine when trying to reboot from ssh sessions).

Comment: Then I think you should unaccept the answer to attract more users (and perhaps edit your question to add these things too), since this is now beyond my level. I think it might be some relaxation of policy for local users (I mean, a local user can always pull the plug).

Comment: @muru Although, now that I try it, it doesn't work for me. Contents of `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/restrict-shutdown.pkla` are exactly what you have there, logged in via SSH, can still shut down via LightDM. Are there permissions I need to set on this file, or packages I need to install?

Comment: @detly you're probably an admin - the OP says the admin user isn't restricted, only regular users are.

Comment: @muru I don't think the LightDM login screen runs as an admin user though...? (Edit: just tried as non admin user, same thing. Shuts down.)

Comment: @detly No, as far as I can remember. And [it should be affected too](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/177436835/shot.png) - are multiple users logged in?

Comment: @muru - Yep, one user is logged in via SSH.